# AngularJS $http post request: [$http:baddata] positions limit

Tags: angularjs, http, post

I would like to send an array of objects via AngularJS $http service.

The array contains more than 400 objects. Each object represents a single product and has typical key-value pairs. Keys are product id, product name, quantity, price and tax.

When I trying to send data, I can see an error in console:

> Error: "[$http:baddata] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.5/$http/baddata?p0={:code=:error, :message=>"positions limit: 300"}&p1={}"

Incidentally, I able to send an array with 300 objects and no more.

This is my code:

```
let json_params = {
"api_token":"my-token",
"invoice": {
    "kind":"vat", 
    "income":"0",
    "number": '123', 
    "sell_date": '2019-01-01', 
    "issue_date": '2019-01-01' 
    "payment_to": '2019-01-01'

    "seller_name": "Sample Name",
    "seller_street" : "Sample Str",
    "seller_post_code" : "12-123",
    "seller_city" : "Warsaw",
    "seller_tax_no": "12234566",
    "positions": $scope.products // AN ARRAY WITH MORE THAN 400 OBJECTS.
}}

$http({
method: 'POST',
url: 'http://example.com/api-endpoint',
data: json_params,
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
console.log( response );
}, function errorCallback(response) {
console.log( response );            
});
```

My question is if is there some limitation for http post request for AngularJS or maybe there is something wrong with my data?

Comment: check this - https://serverfault.com/questions/151090/is-there-a-maximum-size-for-content-of-an-http-post

Comment: My solution is to split one big request to smaller chunks and send them asynchronously. In my case, the first chunk creates a document and if receive a response from the server (with ID of the document), then is able to update it with other chunks. I've used $q.all() method.